# Row sorting/counting in a Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, counting

I'm trying to develop a quality check script that would go through a set of data (in a pandas dataframe) and count the total number of different types of samples. Here's an example from the database:

[image]

The samples in question are everything with

```
XXX123
```

My current script selects and picks all the QC samples like the Blank or IRM, but I am having trouble getting count of the actual XXX123, because some of them are getting two types of duplicates, as internal quality checks.

1. One type is with "ORIG" and "PREP"
2. Second type is with " .1" and " .2"

Additional issue is that rarely one sample will get both, like you can see with XXX123 85-90

Finally, question is how could I possibly account for this? How to tell python this:

- whenever there is one row containing " .1" and the one below
  containing " .2" - count those two entries as 1
- whenever there is one row containing "ORIG" and the one below
  containing "PREPDUP" - count those two entries as 1
- whenever there is one row containing "ORIG .1" and the one below
  containing "ORIG .2" and the third below, containing "PREPDUP" -
  count those three entries as 1.

Please let me know if I can clarify this further. Thanks! This is the code I run currently, however everything below "# Replicates" does not perform as I want, since I can't figure it out:

```
# IRMs
IRMs = CorrectedDF[CorrectedDF['SampleID'].str.match('IRM')]
print('Total numer of IRM samples in the run is: {}' .format(len(IRMs.index)))

# BLANKs 
searchfor = ['blk', 'Blank', 'BLK', 'blank']
BLANKs = CorrectedDF[CorrectedDF['SampleID'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
print('Total numer of BLANKs in the run is: {}' .format(len(BLANKs.index)))

# OREAS 239
searchfor2 = ['OREAS 239', 'oreas 239', 'Oreas 239']
OREAS_239 = CorrectedDF[CorrectedDF['SampleID'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor2))]
print('Total numer of OREAS 239 Samples in the run is: {}' .format(len(OREAS_239.index)))

# Cal Standards 
searchfor3 = ['Standard', 'Au 15']
CalSTD = CorrectedDF[CorrectedDF['SampleID'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor3))]
print('Total numer of Cal Standard Samples in the run is: {}' .format(len(CalSTD.index)))

# Prep samples
searchfor4 = ['Prep']
Prep = CorrectedDF[CorrectedDF['SampleID'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor4))]
print('Total numer of Prep Samples in the run is: {}' .format(len(Prep.index)))

# Replicates
searchfor5 = ['ORIG', 'PREPDUP']
Replicates = CorrectedDF[CorrectedDF['SampleID'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor5))]
print('Total numer of Replicate Samples in the run is: {}' .format(len(Replicates.index)))

print('Total numer of ALL Samples in the run is: {}' .format(len(CorrectedDF.index)))
ClientSamples = len(CorrectedDF.index) - (len(IRMs.index) + len(BLANKs.index)
                                          + len(OREAS_239.index) + len(CalSTD.index) 
                                          + len(Prep.index) + len(Replicates.index))
print('Total numer of Client-ONLY Samples in the run is: {}' .format(ClientSamples))
```

Comment: Could you provide the `csv` in text format please.

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Label'].str.extract('(XXX123 \d+-\d+)').nunique()
```

You can just use regex to extract what you are looking for, then use nunique to find out how many unique values there are.

Comment: That works, thank you. However, I guess I forgot another thing when I was looking at the dataset. So basically there are three types of duplicates in those jobs:
1. with ".1" and ".2" at the end
2. with "ORIG" and "PREP" at the end
3. but there is also duplicates that should NOT count as one, which end with "A" and "B". So in other words, those should not be counted as 1 but as two. Example "XXX123 A" and "XXX123 B"